# What is different between below method on flex in action script3?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash, air

NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();  - this  method is used for exit the application of flex/air .
application.close();  - this method also used for exit the application of flex/air -
So what is different?

Answer (score 1):

He is referring to NativeApplication.exit() vs WindowedApplication.close().

> **WindowedApplication.close()** 
>  Closes the
>   application's NativeWindow (the
>   initial native window opened by the
>   application). This action is
>   cancelable.

Calling close() on the application window will effectively shut down the application, but using the exit() method on NativeApplication is the proper way to terminate it. See the following link for more info:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=app_launch_1.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I am understanding your question entirely because I am not finding an application.close() method.

Here is the documentation on NativeApplication, an AIR only class: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/desktop/NativeApplication.html#exit()

It defines the exit method like this:

> Terminates this application.
>
> The call to the exit() method will
>   return; the shutdown sequence does not
>   begin until the currently executing
>   code (such as a current event handler)
>   has completed. Pending asynchronous
>   operations are canceled and may or may
>   not complete.
>
> Note that an exiting event is not
>   dispatched. If an exiting event is
>   required by application logic, call
>   NativeApplication.nativeApplication.dispatchEvent(),
>   passing in an Event object of type
>   exiting. Likewise, closing and close
>   events are not dispatched before
>   application windows are closed. If
>   windows should be notified before your
>   application exits, you can dispatch
>   closing events for each open window.
>   If a window close event is required,
>   call the window's close() method
>   before exiting.

Here is the documetation on Application, a Flex class: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/Application.html#methodSummary

It does not seem to have a close() method associated with it.  Are you possibly confusing the application class with a window class that you need to close before calling the NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit() ?

I would be happy to help you research this further if you can clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

One completely exits the application, the other only closes the main window. It's important to understand the difference. On a Mac, for instance, closing all of an application's windows often leaves that application running in the dock. This is rarely the case on Windows, but if you have a dock icon, you should get similar behavior, I think.